# Why is numpy rounding in this case?

Tags: python, numpy

You know how sometimes a code error feels like you must be losing your mind? I thought I was and then I determined that there's some sort of rounding error here.

Why is the first cell in `result` not equal to the same cell in `expected`? This is obviously rounding (see second to last test), but it feels like bug-level rounding to me. Second, if 1 - .9 * .9 is not .19, why isn't is .19000000000004 or whatever I usually see when there's a rounding thing happening.

```py
def calc_negation(negations):
    takens = 1. - negations
    return 1. - np.prod(takens, axis=1, keepdims=True)

result = calc_negation(np.array([[.1, .1], [.5, .5]]))
expected =  np.array([[.19], [.75]])

print(result)
print(result == expected)  # show the failed equality.

assert result.shape == (2, 1)
assert result.shape == expected.shape
assert result.dtype == expected.dtype

assert expected[0, 0] == .19  # why is this okay!?!
assert expected[1, 0] == .75
assert np.allclose(result, expected)  # why is numpy rounding 1 - (.9 * .9)? 
assert np.array_equal(result, expected)  # FAILS!
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Right.  You can't ever reliably compare floating point numbers for exactness.  The answer probably IS .1900000000004, but numpy tries to present human-friendly numbers by rounding them for display.

Comment: You don't like 53 bits of FP mantissa? Ok, try `import decimal`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html

Answer (score 3):

You should read the linked answers about floating point in general. But here is what specifically happened in this case.

Since `expected =  np.array([[.19], [.75]])`, `assert expected[0, 0] == .19` had better be OK: you wrote 0.19 both times. Whatever 0.19 parses to, you should at least get the same value both times. Namely 0.190000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625 (this is the closest double precision IEEE float to 0.19, converted to decimal *exactly* as it is, without rounding as we usually do)

> Second, if 1 - .9 * .9 is not .19, why isn't is .19000000000004 or whatever I usually see when there's a rounding thing happening.

It was 0.18999999999999994671 actually, but by default floats are not printed to such a precision.